# How to generate random colors from array for css divs with same class

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I can't make javascript to create a random color for each div (individually) from an existing array all desired divs have class of "view" (I'm really tired from trying so any help will be greatly appreciated ).

```js
var colors = [
  "rgb(52,152,219)",
  "rgb(243,156,18)",
  "rgb(155,89,182)",
  "rgb(30,130,76)",
  "rgb(219,10,91)",
  "rgb(102,51,153)",
  "rgb(58,83,155)",
  "rgb(31,58,147)",
  "rgb(217,30,24)"
];
function theFunction() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("view").style.backgroundColor =
    colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)];
}
theFunction();
```

```css
.onetwo {
  width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  left: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #efefef;
}
.view {
  width: 260px;
  height: 260px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #e6e6e6;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #e6e6e6;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #e6e6e6;
  cursor: default;
  background: #00baf1;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="onetwo">
    <div class="view" ; id="DIVDIV">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper
        porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="view" ; id="DIVDIV">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper
        porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="view" ; id="DIVDIV">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper
        porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="view" ; id="DIVDIV">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper
        porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="view" ; id="DIVDIV">
      <p>WLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper
        porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="view" ; id="DIVDIV">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper
        porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="view" ; id="DIVDIV">
      <p>We offer Comfortable Dorms for our students to be a step closer to the university We offer Comfortable Dorms for our students to be a step closer to the university We offer Comfortable Dorms for our students to be a step closer to the university
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="view" ; id="DIVDIV">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper
        porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="view" ; id="DIVDIV">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper
        porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access the `style` property of the "node list" (collection) of DOM elements that were returned from:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("view")
```

A collection doesn't have a `style`, but the DOM elements inside the collection do. You have to iterate over each of the elements within that collection and set the `style` property of the actual DOM elements themselves.

While you can use a traditional `for` counting loop. JavaScript arrays support a **[`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** looping method that makes setting up the loop and accessing each element within the array much easier. But, not all browsers support `.forEach()` on node lists returned from DOM functions, so you just need to convert the node list into an Array to be able to call `.forEach()`.

**Also, it's best not to use [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)** as this returns a *"live node list"* which causes the entire DOM to be scanned again each time the cache variable is used. **[`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)** returns a static node list that performs better and should be used in most cases.

You also have some invalid HTML with `;` appearing inside your tags. Those should be removed:

```
<div class="view" ; id="DIVDIV1">
```

Additionally, the CSS `box-shadow` property has been standard and has had broad browser support for several years now. There is no need to use vendor prefixes with it.

Lastly, you should not have multiple elements with the same value for their `id` attribute. `id`'s are meant to be unique within an document and having multiple elements with the same `id` can/will cause problems down the line in CSS and JavaScript. If you are looking for a way to group all the elements, use a single CSS class for each of them.

```js
var colors = [
  "rgb(52,152,219)",
  "rgb(243,156,18)",
  "rgb(155,89,182)",
  "rgb(30,130,76)",
  "rgb(219,10,91)",
  "rgb(102,51,153)",
  "rgb(58,83,155)",
  "rgb(31,58,147)",
  "rgb(217,30,24)"
];

function theFunction() {
  // Get all the elements that use the "view" class but do it using querySelectorAll
  var divs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".view"));
  
  // Loop through the array of divs
  divs.forEach(function(div){
    // Set the background color of each div
    div.style.backgroundColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  });

}
theFunction();
```

```css
.onetwo{
    width: 1000px;
    position: relative;
    left: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #efefef;
}
.view {
    width: 260px; 
    height: 260px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #e6e6e6;
    cursor: default;
    background: #00baf1;
    display: inline-block;
    margin : 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="onetwo">
    <div class="view" id="DIVDIV1"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla.  </p></div>
    <div class="view" id="DIVDIV2"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla.  </p></div>
    <div class="view" id="DIVDIV3"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla.  </p></div>
    <div class="view" id="DIVDIV4"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. </p></div>
    <div class="view" id="DIVDIV5"><p>WLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla.   </p></div>
    <div class="view" id="DIVDIV6"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. </p></div>
    <div class="view" id="DIVDIV7"><p>We offer Comfortable Dorms for our students to be a step closer to the university We offer Comfortable Dorms for our students to be a step closer to the university We offer Comfortable Dorms for our students to be a step closer to the university </p></div>
    <div class="view" id="DIVDIV8"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla.  </p></div>
    <div class="view" id="DIVDIV9"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla.  </p></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it is really amazing but there is a problem when i copy the code to the JavaScript sheet the code doesn't excute in the browser I checked everything but still doesn't work I know this is annoying but I hope this is the last hurdle we face and thanks . . .

Comment: @Jonathan make sure that the script is inserted into the document just before the closing of the body tag so that by the time the JavaScript is executed all of the HTML will have been parsed into memory

Comment: @Jonathan You're welcome. I've just updated my answer to inform you of some HTML syntax problems that you have, so take another look.

Answer (score 1):

1. The function getElementsByClassName returns HTMLCollection, so you can't just set the `style` on that collection - you need to go over all the elements and set the style on each of them.
2. The function you created is called `theFunction` (with capital F), and javascript is case sensitive, so you must use exactly the same name.

Here is the fix based on your code:

```js
var colors = ["rgb(52,152,219)", "rgb(243,156,18)", "rgb(155,89,182)", "rgb(30,130,76)", "rgb(219,10,91)", "rgb(102,51,153)", "rgb(58,83,155)", "rgb(31,58,147)", "rgb(217,30,24)"];
function theFunction() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("view");
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      elements[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)];
  }
}
theFunction();
```

```css
.onetwo{

    width: 1000px;
    position: relative;
    left: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #efefef;
}
.view {
    width: 260px; 
    height: 260px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #e6e6e6;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #e6e6e6;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #e6e6e6;
    cursor: default;
    background: #00baf1;
    display: inline-block;
    margin : 1px;
}
```

```html
<body>
   <div class = "onetwo">
  <div class="view"; id="DIVDIV"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla.  </p></div>
          <div class="view"; id="DIVDIV"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla.  </p></div>
          <div class="view"; id="DIVDIV"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla.  </p></div>
          <div class="view"; id="DIVDIV"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. </p></div>
          <div class="view"; id="DIVDIV"><p>WLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla.   </p></div>
          <div class="view"; id="DIVDIV"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. </p></div>
        <div class="view"; id="DIVDIV"><p>We offer Comfortable Dorms for our students to be a step closer to the university We offer Comfortable Dorms for our students to be a step closer to the university We offer Comfortable Dorms for our students to be a step closer to the university </p></div>
        <div class="view"; id="DIVDIV"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla.  </p></div>
        <div class="view"; id="DIVDIV"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla.  </p></div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it is really amazing but there is a problem when i copy the code to the JavaScript sheet the code doesn't excute in the browser I checked everything but still doesn't work I know this is annoying but I hope this is the last hurdle we face and thanks . . .

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("view"))
    .forEach((item) => {
        function randValue() { return Math.floor(Math.random()*255)}
        item.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb('+randValue()+','+randValue()+','+randValue()+')';
    })
```

As other answerers have stated, you can't iterate over a HTMLCollection, but you can convert it to an array using `Array.from`. So, we identify all elements with the `view` class by using the call to `document.getElementsByClassName`, then convert it to an array.

Now, we iterate over every element within that array, and create an RGB color value, and assign that to the `item.style.backgroundColor`, which updates the item we're currently iterating over's backgroundColor property.

Your question requests random colors, but I didn't know if that meant random within the array you provided. My approach provides truly random color generation for each element.

However, if you require random from an array of options, you could use this approach, which is very similar.

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("view"))
        .forEach((item) => {
        var colors = [
              "rgb(52,152,219)",
              "rgb(243,156,18)",
              "rgb(155,89,182)",
              "rgb(30,130,76)",
              "rgb(219,10,91)",
              "rgb(102,51,153)",
              "rgb(58,83,155)",
              "rgb(31,58,147)",
              "rgb(217,30,24)"
            ];
            item.style.backgroundColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
        })
```